Ok for electrical wires to be touching gas lines?
We just had our gas lines above our kitchen re-piped. The pictures show the gas lines are touching electrical wires.  Anyone know if this is safe and up to code standards (please provide code number if possible)?  We are concerned for our safety!


As long as there is no pinching/binding of the cables against the gas lines, it should be safe.  Just hanging over/under the lines should not cause problems.  Gas leaks and sparks from switches/motors/relays or as Tim found out about the clapper, is what causes the boom.

Thank you crip659.  So there is no concern if the electrical wire is actually touching the gas line?  We are definitely concerned about a spark from the electric wire if there is a gas leak if it's that close to the gas line.  Do you know of any code of regulations that discusses this?  Thank you again!

The insulation on cables is quite robust.  Just simple hanging/touching should not damage the cable.  The cable and/or gas line must be protected from nails/screws if closer than 1.5 inch of the drywall surface at studs by metal plates.

Where are you seeing sparks???

The wires are insulated. There should be no sparks. There should also be no gas leak. As long as you don't cut, nail, or otherwise damage these, there is no danger. And if you ever do have a gas leak, evacuate immediately and let professionals deal with it.

As long as there aren't any sharp protuberances on the gas line, it'll be fine.  If there are, just file them smooth.

There is nothing especially wrong with a wire touching a gas line.
Air ducts (first picture) are more of a problem, as they have sharp edges and vibrate.  That can cut through a cable over time.
As much as possible, electric cables should be fixed to framing to prevent various problems.
As much as possible, wires should be kept half way between floor, ceiling and wall surfaces.  So for example the wire in the first picture going under the gas pipe, should go above it, and be fixed to the joist half way up it.  This makes it less likely to be struck by screws, nails and saws through the ceiling.
